# WMI error "Invalid method Parameters" when running Win32_Volume.Defrag

Tags: c#, exception, wmi

Today I wanted to run the Defrag utility through WMI but this exception doesn't allow me do this. What have I done wrong? I invoke a method (I did it by MSDN guide) but it throws a ManagementException.

[image: ManagementException]

Answer (score 1):

You have to enumerate through `Win32_Volume` entities. Here is a sample with `DefragAnalysis` method.

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Volume");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    string name = (string)mo.GetPropertyValue("Name");
    if (name == @"C:\")
    {
        var props = new object[2];
        mo.InvokeMethod("DefragAnalysis", props);
    }
}
```